# Variable nth-child(n) with before and after

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make "1" become variable/dynamic.
When I click 2nd button, "1" will changed to "2"

```
#button li:nth-child(1) a {
background-color: #5cb85c;
}
#button li:nth-child(1) a:before {
border-color: #5cb85c;
border-left-color: transparent;
}
#button li:nth-child(1) a:after {
border-left-color: #5cb85c;
}
```

The first css class is working using

```
$("#button li:nth-child(2) a").css("background-color", "#5cb85c");
```

While :before and :after are not.

Or any other solution will do.
When I click the 2nd button, same set of css will be applied. And on the 3rd button. And so on.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION** from @giorgio

Finally after lots of tries from giorgio's solution, here's how it worked based on my sample css.

```
.button-select a {
background-color: #5cb85c !important;
}
.button-select a:before {
border-color: #5cb85c !important;
border-left-color: transparent !important;
}
.button-select a:after {
border-left-color: #5cb85c !important;
}
```

I need to add !important to override the default style.
Then on my onClick,

```
$('#buttons li').eq(n).toggleClass('button-select');
```

`n` is the index of `<li>` in `<ul id = "buttons">`

Comment: Instead of changing the `background-color` add a class (e.g. `active`). Then you can select the next element with `$(".active").next()`

Comment: Thanks @caramba for correcting

Comment: I'll try your suggestion @Andreas Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most easy solution is not to use `:nth-child()` but to set a few classes and apply the `::before:`/`::after` selectors on them. Eg;

```
.background-red::before { background: red; }
.background-blue::before { background: blue; }
```

Now with jQuery / javascript look for the elements you want to alter and toggle the classes. Eg;

```
$('.my-selector').eq(n).toggleClass('background-red');
```

The problems with changing pseudo-selectors is they're not part of the DOM; you will not be able to alter them directly..

Comment: Is this correct? Sorry I'm new to css.
$('#button').eq(2).toggleClass('button-select');

#button-select:before {
 border-color: #5cb85c;
 border-left-color: transparent;
}

Comment: well, as it's a class, your css should be `.button-select { ... }` instead of `#button-select { ... }`, which is a selector for an id